# What Excel function do I use to find the largest total of combined cells in a spreadsheet and populate that number in 2 similar cells?

Tags: excel

I have a fishing weight spreadsheet, trying to pull the highest total from a number of months, in which my Calculation totals tab contains all the data.

I need to find the largest value for the year for big bass and pull that total in a YTD column. For example, the highest value for one team is 6 lbs, 3 oz (column containing pounds, column next to it containing ounces) for a highest monthly total, and I want it to select that highest amount and pull that value in YTD totals in the same format 6 lbs, 3 oz. My formula is looking down the entire list and stopping on the first number that is highest, which is correct; however, it is looking in the 2nd column for the highest number as well. How do I create a formula to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the formula for pulling in the highest pounds from the entire list.
`=IF(P4<>0,MAX(IF(C:C=P4,I:I)),"")`

This is the formula for pulling in the highest ounces from the entire list.
`=IF(P4<>0,MAX(IF(C:C=P4,J:J)),"")`

I am not advanced enough to know how to edit this formula to make sure the 2nd formula is keeping the ounces with it.

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to avoid getting downvoted your question.

Comment: Share some sample data using a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) but don't make it your real data because I'm hungry and don't want to read about food.

Comment: Is there a way I can share my spreadsheet? I can't seem to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't really support posting full files. FWIW, plain-text is encouraged since it's portable and searchable. If you're still working at this, maybe try an XLS->markdown converter and edit your post. Here is one, but I haven't tried it yet! https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Answer (score 0):

Since your actual value text is spread across two columns, you have two options.

**Method 1**

Proceed with what you have, though the max ounces function won't work out. You're right - it's separate from the Max lb, and you can't put them back together using MAX() alone.

Instead, find the row of the Max Pounds Value cell. Then you can collect the oz value by using INDIRECT() to create the cell address of the Max Oz cell.

Concatenate the Max lb + Max oz values inside your YTD Max output cell.

You can use this as a guide, but substitute in your own Max lb function wherever I have used MAX(A:A). This should get you pretty close to what you need.

| lbs | oz |  | Max lb | Max lb Row | oz value at row | YTD Max Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 12 |  | =MAX(A:A) | =MATCH(MAX(A:A), A:A, 0) | =INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)) | =MAX(A:A)&"lb "&INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(MAX(A:A), A:A, 0))&"oz" |
| 7 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 13 |  |  |  |  |  |

My test data looks like this:

[image: screenshot of XLS with data output using functions given]

**Method 2**

Create a third column that calculates the maximum weight as oz only. You can use your existing data, of course, and even hide the calculation column so that it doesn't mess up the appearance of your records. Then, search for your maximum oz-only value using one of your existing functions, and send that across to the YTD Max output cell.

When you have the maximum value in oz (6lb 3oz being 99oz) ... then convert that back into lb/oz using MOD(). The formula you need will be similar to:

```
=LET(Max,99,ROUND(Max/16,0)&"lb "&MOD(Max,16))&"oz"
```

Instead of 99, you'll need to drop in whatever formula you use that returns the maximum total oz in your records.

Answer (score 0):

Try his formula

```
=HSTACK(INT(MAX(A1:A7*16+B1:B7)/16),MOD(MAX(A1:A7*16+B1:B7),16))
```

[image]

**ADD**

Assume that the names are in column C like in the sample, then use formula:

```
=HSTACK(INT(MAX(A1:A7*16+B1:B7)/16),MOD(MAX(A1:A7*16+B1:B7),16),INDEX(C1:C7,MATCH(MAX(A1:A7*16+B1:B7),A1:A7*16+B1:B7,0)))
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | Name1 |
| 5 | 11 | Name2 |
| 5 | 3 | Name3 |
| 2 | 6 | Name2 |
| 9 | 2 | Name5 |
| 5 | 8 | Name6 |
| 1 | 3 | Name1 |

Comment: How do I preface the formula you suggested to find and match up a name associated with the highest pounds and ounces I am looking for?  I tried this, but it didn't work -- =IF(P4<>0,MAX(IF(C:C=P4,HSTACK(INT(MAX(D1:D500*16+E1:E500)/16),MOD(MAX(A1:A500*16+E1:E500),16)))))

Comment: Pls. find the enhanced formula.